Unable to launch Flutter project in a Dart-only workspace?

I tried to run my dart code and got this error message. Unable to launch Flutter project in a Dart-only workspace. Please open a folder closer to your Flutter project root or increase the value of the "dart.projectSearchDepth" setting.

I suggest creating a new Dart project using the command: dart create <name_of_project> while standing in the directory you want the project to be created in.

In order to run Flutter, you need a Flutter workspace that includes the platform files for the platform you are trying to run Flutter for. Otherwise Flutter isn't going to know how to build and run Flutter to run your project on your system. You either need to run the dart code using the dart command or use the flutter create command to create a proper Flutter workspace.
